# Plot live bar chart together with line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a csv file that updates data of two stocks live when the market opens. I have some codes(sample found from internet) that plots bid and ask price of the two stocks, in two subplots. The program works fine and it looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
plt.plot([], [])
plt.plot([], [])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0], sharex=ax2)
plt.plot([], [])
plt.plot([], [])

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\Desktop\test\stock_data.csv')
    x = data.index
    y1 = data.bid_p_x
    y2 = data.ask_p_x
    y3 = data.bid_p_y
    y4 = data.ask_p_y

    line1, line2 = ax1.lines
    line1.set_data(x, y1)
    line2.set_data(x, y2)
    line3, line4 = ax2.lines
    line3.set_data(x, y3)
    line4.set_data(x, y4)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=250)
ax1.grid(True)
ax2.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The reason I choose this code is because I can zoom in freely anywhere on the graph while the plot is updating every 0.25s(rather than the frame keeps changing back to default every time the plot updates).

However when I tried to plot a live bar chart together with a live line plot, i.e. line plot for the price of one stock and bar chart for its trade volume, I got some errors. So I changed `plt.plot([], [])` to `plt.bar([], [])` under `ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])`:

```
...
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
plt.bar([], [])
plt.bar([], [])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0], sharex=ax2)
plt.plot([], [])
plt.plot([], [])

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\Desktop\test\stock_data.csv')

    x = data.index
    y1 = data.price_x
    y2 = data.last_volume_x

    line1, line2 = ax1.lines
    line1.set_data(x, y1)
    line3, line4 = ax2.lines
    line3.set_data(x, y2)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=250)
ax1.grid(True)
ax2.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
...
```

I get this error:`line3, line4 = ax2.lines`, `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`.

I also tried to define `line1` and `line2` right after `ax1` and `ax2` are defined:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
line2, = plt.bar([], [])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0], sharex=ax2)
line1, = plt.plot([], [])
plt.plot([], [])

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\Desktop\test\stock_data.csv')

    x = data.index
    y1 = data.price_x
    y2 = data.last_volume_x

    line1.set_data(x, y1)
    line2.set_data(x, y2)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=250)
ax1.grid(True)
ax2.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I got the same error: `line2, = plt.bar([], [])`, `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)`.

It seems that bar is different from plot fundamentally, and how do I fix this? My only requirement is still that I can navigate anywhere on the plots, while the plots are updating.